# Network access when the Android phone is asleep

Tags: android, sleep, wifi

I'm using a combination of alarm (set with `AlarmManager`) and background service to periodically synchronize data in my application.

The only problem I have is that when sleep policy terminates Wi-Fi connection the synchronization no longer works.

Is there a way to "wake up" the Wi-Fi connection that has been put to sleep? GMail somehow manages to do that because it notifies me about new e-mail even if the phone entered sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

[update]You can use a [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to keep WiFi active, while holding the lock.

Using an `AlarmManager` and a `Service` says to me your service is running only for a very short time!? I think (though can't say for certain) that you should make your service a forground service (check the blog for a good way to implement this on both 1.x and 2.x+) and leave the `AlarmManager` out of it.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of those foreground services. Will it however solve my problem with suspended Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: I know about the WifiLock but it doesn't solve the problem. My application would have to acquire this lock and keep it indefinitely. I'd rather just wake up the connection when my app wants to sync. Anyway, I think I'll leave it as it is. If the user sets such sleep policy, he/she must be aware that sync won't work.