# Android: Does internet (mobile data connection) switch off when mobile goes to sleep?

Tags: android, service

I am running a remote service which has a handler which does an operation every 15 minutes (handler.postDelayed()) which involves making an internet request. Sometimes i notice that it does not happen. Does the internet (mobile data connection get switched off when the mobile sleeps or processor sleeps). What happens during this time ?

I guess internet gets turned off when the screen goes to sleep. What could be the efficient way to make sure that in the required time interval(half an hour) it wakes up (turns the internet on) and does the job in the remote service? This service is supposed to run in the background throughout. Can i do this with an AlarmManager (can it trigger some job to happen in a remote service)?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a related question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487132/1012381), you can give a try to [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) if you use only Wi-Fi for this service.
Another reason is maybe your service is destroyed by Android when it sees no use. If it is the case you can try the [Foreground service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) option. Note this does not guarantee the service won't be destroyed but the priority compared to other service will be decreased, thus giving more chance to your service to survive.

Comment: I am returning a START_STICKY in its start so even if it gets destroyed, it will restart the service. Or should i be using AlarmManager instead of Handler ? Can i use an AlarmManager within a remote service ?